# PHP Curl wrong redirect

Tags: javascript, php, redirect, curl, cloudflare

I used to get some information in a website, using curl to login and show the information, but now the website is using cloudflare. The problem is I can't follow the redirect because the website uses javascript.

I think it can be pretty simple to solve, because I use php curl on a local host, and after 5 seconds the message "**Checking your browser before accessing example.**" redirects me to: **www.localhost/LINKOFTHEREDIRECT** instead of going to **www.example.com/LINKOFTHEREDIRECT** and showing me the correct webpage.

Here is my code:

```
<?php

$url0 = "http://example.com/login.php";
$url = "http://example.com/pageIwant.php";

    $user_agent='Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; WOW64; rv:32.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/32.0';

    $options = array(
        CURLOPT_USERAGENT      => $user_agent, //set user agent
        CURLOPT_COOKIESESSION  => true,     // enable cookies
        CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE     =>"C:/Program Files/XAMPP/htdocs/cp/cookies.txt", //set cookie file
        CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR      =>"C:/Program Files/XAMPP/htdocs/cp/cookies.txt", //set cookie jar
        CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST  =>"GET",        //set request type post or get
        CURLOPT_POST           =>false,        //set to GET
        CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,     // return web page
        CURLOPT_HEADER         => false,    // don't return headers
        CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION => true,     // follow redirects
        CURLOPT_ENCODING       => "",       // handle all encodings
        CURLOPT_AUTOREFERER    => true,     // set referer on redirect
        CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT => 20,      // timeout on connect
        CURLOPT_TIMEOUT        => 20,      // timeout on response
        CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS      => 10,       // stop after 10 redirects
    );

    $ch0      = curl_init( $url0 );
    curl_setopt_array( $ch0, $options );
    $content0 = curl_exec( $ch0 );
    curl_close( $ch0 );

    $ch      = curl_init( $url );
    curl_setopt_array( $ch, $options );
    $content = curl_exec( $ch );
    $err     = curl_errno( $ch );
    $errmsg  = curl_error( $ch );
    $header  = curl_getinfo( $ch );
    curl_close( $ch );

    $header['errno']   = $err;
    $header['errmsg']  = $errmsg;
    $header['content'] = $content;

    echo $content; ?>
```

And here is the javascript:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  //<![CDATA[
  (function() {
    var a = function() {
        try {
          return !!window.addEventListener
        } catch (e) {
          return !1
        }
      },
      b = function(b, c) {
        a() ? document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", b, c) : document.attachEvent("onreadystatechange", b)
      };
    b(function() {
      var a = document.getElementById('cf-content');
      a.style.display = 'block';
      setTimeout(function() {
        var t, r, a, f, YvDgwfU = {
          "uxTkX": +((+!![] + []) + (!+[] + !![]))
        };
        t = document.createElement('div');
        t.innerHTML = "<a href='/'>x</a>";
        t = t.firstChild.href;
        r = t.match(/https?:\/\//)[0];
        t = t.substr(r.length);
        t = t.substr(0, t.length - 1);
        a = document.getElementById('jschl-answer');
        f = document.getElementById('challenge-form');;
        YvDgwfU.uxTkX *= +((!+[] + !![] + !![] + !![] + []) + (!+[] + !![] + !![] + !![]));
        YvDgwfU.uxTkX -= +((+!![] + []) + (!+[] + !![] + !![] + !![] + !![] + !![] + !![]));
        YvDgwfU.uxTkX -= +((!+[] + !![] + !![] + !![] + !![] + []) + (+[]));
        a.value = parseInt(YvDgwfU.uxTkX, 10) + t.length;
        f.submit();
      }, 5850);
    }, false);
  })();
  //]]>
</script>
```

Comment: You are never going to get cURL to follow a javascript redirect in any out of the box fashion.  You would have to parse the document for javascript and try to glean from there (if possible) where the redirect is going to send you to.

Answer (score 0):

"message "Checking your browser before accessing example." redirects me to"

Whatever you're doing is triggering a DDoS rule on the site and/or the site owner has decided to turn on the feature.

If the website is ok with you doing what you're doing, you should ask the site owner to whitelist the IPs you're doing this from.